# Kendo UI Grid - Remove group column?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

When enabling grouping on a KendoGrid, a blank column is automatically added that creates a sort of tab space for rows inside a group. See the example here: http://dojo.telerik.com/atiTi/3

Is there a clean way to remove this column so that both groups and rows are left aligned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way is to just add a style:

```
.k-group-cell {
    display: none;
}
```

You can do it with jquery as well:

http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-hide-grouping-column